# Why doesn't Django-simple-math-captcha render question?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to integrate Django-simple-math-captcha in my project, but the form doesn't render the question. I've followed all the steps in the docs, and render the form:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field.label_tag }}
  {{ field }}
  {% if field.errors %}
      {{ field.errors }}
  {% else %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

I get the captcha label i.e. Captcha:

and the captcha answer input,

all captcha error messages,

but no question. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you try `{{ field.question_html }}` instead of `{{ field }}`  ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that didn't work.

Comment: I've also tried {{ field.question_tmpl }} , {{ field.question }} , {{ field.captcha.question }} etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this package on Django 2.0+ and the captcha question doesn't get rendered. Here is the output when I print the form from my view:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 28, 2018 - 05:52:00
Django version 2.0.8, using settings 'stackover.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<input type="text" name="captcha_0" size="5" required id="id_captcha_0" />
<input type="hidden" name="captcha_1" value="2b05507f9541c630c35d55509b05deea6e04e8cc" required id="id_captcha_1" />
[28/Sep/2018 05:52:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 118
```

If you go through the sources of this package, you will see that the question is rendered as an html class `captcha-question`, which is missing in the above html output. However after downgrading Django to version 1.8 a mere `{{ form }}` in my template rendered all three fields as shown below i.e. question, input and hidden hashed answer. So if you are using Django 2.0+ then you need to downgrade to use this package or you have to tweak this package to work with your current version (That would be some work I guess!). Here is the simple output I got on printing the captcha form in my view:

```
Django version 1.8, using settings 'stackover.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

<tr><th><label for="id_captcha_0">Captcha:</label></th>
<td><span class="captcha-question">What is the result of 1 - 1?</span>
<input id="id_captcha_0" name="captcha_0" size="5" type="text" />
<input id="id_captcha_1" name="captcha_1" type="hidden" value="aad5d3b0165de882bc40cfbfa47f8262d6d8f9da" /></td></tr>
[28/Sep/2018 06:19:03]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 425
```

Comment: Ah, ok, makes sense. I'll look through the package code and see if there's anything I can do, else I'll look for another solution. Maybe it'd be best just to use google reCaptcha, but I was trying to avoid sending user data to their API. Do you have any suggestions for a good captcha to use with Django? I also tried Django-simple-captcha, but ran into problems validating the captcha, always returning a "invalid CAPTCHA" error message. After looking through SO and GitHub some said it may be missing libraries for Pillow, but I installed those with brew. Anyway, thanks for your help Paandittya.